# \hangparas not working in Memoir

Tags: memoir, paragraphs

I am trying to get hanging paragraphs in my Memoir document. It isn't working. The MWE below doesn't cause errors, but the paragraphs are not indented. E.g. the word "that" is directly under the D in Definition. I would like it to be slightly indented.

MWE begins

```
\documentclass[11pt, statementpaper]{memoir}
\title{Interesting words}
\author{Peter Flom}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}


\usepackage{leading}
\leading{14pt}

\setlrmarginsandblock{0.75in}{*}{*}
%\setulmarginsandblock{0.75in}{0.75in}{*}

\setsubsecheadstyle{\scshape\raggedright}


%\newcommand{\entry}[2]{\medskip\noindent{\Large\textbf{#1} (#2)\par}}
\newcommand{\entry}[2]{\medskip\noindent{\Large\textbf{#1} \normalsize{#2} \par}}



\newcommand{\sclabel}[1]{\leavevmode{\normalfont\scshape #1}}
%% Less spacing around lists
\firmlists

\begin{document}
\begin{hangparas}{.2in}{1}

\entry{antipelargy}{Presumably it rhymes with can tie del urge see} \index{antipelargy}
      \begin{flexlabelled}{sclabel}{0pt}{0.5em}{0.5em}{*}{\leftmargin}
         \item[Definition]
         Reciprocal love or kindness, especially that between parents and children. \cite{OED1971} The adjectival form is \emph{antipelargic}.
         \item[Etymology]
         From Greek \emph{antipelargia} (mutual love) via Latin and French \emph{antipelargie} (same meaning). The root is with stork (the bird) which was believed (by the Greeks) to be particularly affectionate (this may be the origin of the notion that storks deliver babies).
         \item[Usage]
         How odd that we have no other word for this and that this word is so rare. It isn't even in most dictionaries.
         \item[Examples] \leavevmode
         \begin{quote}
           Antipelargy is key to the survival of the species.
         \end{quote}
         \item[Frequency]
         There were no uses of \emph{antipelargy} in Google Ngram Viewer.
      \end{flexlabelled} \vspace{0.5in}


\end{hangparas}
\end{document}
```

MWE ENDS

Comment: Unrelated, always remember to run `\checkandfixthelayout` when you have changed the layout in memoir (here the marginsandblock commands).

Comment: `flexlabelled` is based on `list`, so it uses `\parshape` that overrides `\hangindent` as set by `hangparas`.

Answer (score 3):

The definition of `flexlabelled` is

```latex
% memoir.cls, line 4739:
\newenvironment{flexlabelled}[6]%
  {\list{}{\nametest{#2}{*}%
           \ifsamename\else \labelwidth #2  \fi
           \nametest{#3}{*}%
           \ifsamename\else \labelsep #3 \fi
           \nametest{#4}{*}%
           \ifsamename\else \itemindent #4 \fi
           \nametest{#5}{*}%
           \ifsamename\else \leftmargin #5 \fi
           \nametest{#6}{*}%
           \ifsamename\else  \rightmargin #6 \fi
           \def\m@malabel{\@nameuse{#1}} \let\makelabel\m@malabel}}%
  {\endlist}
```

This means the environment is based on `list`, that sets

```
\parshape \@ne \@totalleftmargin \linewidth
```

in *every* paragraph it typesets until overridden or the setting is cancelled at the environment's end.

When TeX is typesetting a paragraph, it uses `\parshape` if its value is nonzero, otherwise `\hangindent`, if its value is nonzero.

So the `list` inside `hangparas` overrides the value of `\hangindent`. You should define your environment based on `list` as well, if you plan to use `flexlabelled` inside it.

Comment: Thanks! Any pointers on how to define the environment to do this? (Or a pointer to a place where I can learn)?  I've never defined an environment.